# What is a safe way to connect to a API on a separate domain?

Tags: php, xml, api

Background : I am creating a website (in the typical LAMP environment) that connects to a database via a PHP/XML based API on a different domain (but on the same server). The reason for this is that I do not want to have database connection details sitting on the domain I am working on. In order for this to work I've enabled "allow-url-fopen" setting for that domain.

My question is, since this is the only way I know how to do this, does anyone know a better i.e. safer and more secure method of achieivng this result?

Comment: maybe create a limited database account so you can just skip the API all together, but have less issues.

Answer (score 0):

If both the domains reside on the same server you do not need to use HTTP to get connected to MySQL, you can still login to your MySQL server locally providing the right credentials for your domain where the connection information is stored.

But it does not really serve a great security purpose, as if your connection details reside even on the same domain it is not a security loop hole as your PHP pages will not be server in any raw form as long as your webserver is configured to use PHP fine. You can and probably should keep them on same domain. In fact having a publically accessible API for database connection is a bigger loophole